# Max value of $a-b$ given $\frac {a!}{b!}$ multiple of $ 4$ but not of $8$.

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

If $\frac{a!}{b!}$ is a multiple of $4$ but not a multiple of $8$,then what is the maximum value of $a-b$ ?

**My work :** I've tried brute force method by trying different values for $a$ and $b$ to seek for some patters and it "seems" that the maximum value of $a-b$ is $3$. 
But of course if that's true or not I need to prove  or disprove it,which I cant see how to do that.

**P.s** If you can give only hints that would be best.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{a!}{b!} = (b+1)*(b+2)*...*(a-1)*a$

If you have two consecutive numbers multiplied, then one will be even, the other odd, and the product of the two will be even. If you have 3 consecutive numbers multiplied, then you will have either *ODD x EVEN x ODD* or *EVEN x ODD x EVEN* and if you have 4 consecutive numbers multiplied, then you will definitely have two evens and two odds.

If you have two consecutive even numbers, then one will be a multiple of 4 and the second even number will make the product into a multiple of eight.

Comment: Pardon sir but how do you get the terms (b+1)(b+2)... in your expansion ?

Comment: $\frac{10!}{5!} = \frac{1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10}{1*2*3*4*5} = 6*7*8*9*10$

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it may be better to think of the numbers modulo $4$, rather than just $2$.  In that case, the sequence of numbers you have to choose from (in order to select an interval to multiply) is

odd, even, odd, divisible by $4$, odd, even, odd, divisible by $4$, odd, $\ldots$

or, if we count the factors of $2$, we have

$0, 1, 0, 2+, 0, 1, 0, 2+, 0, \ldots$

where $2+$ denotes two *or more* factors of $2$.  Can you show how large an interval you can have before you are forced to embrace three or more factors of $2$?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what are numbers modulo 4 ?

Comment: The remainder left after dividing the number by 4: (0, 4, 8, 12...) are 0 mod 4,  (1, 5, 9, 13...) are 1 mod 4, ...